# How to reload page after navigating from another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

// I am using below code for navigating one screen to another i.e Home page .
But when am navigating home page , I have to refresh the page ..reload . In current , when i am coming to home screen non of the life  cycle method is getting call . Specially UserAvatar  component I have to refresh ,or recall .
Please suggest

```
    <View style={{textTransform: 'lowercase'}}><YellowBtn label="Go to 
  Dashboard"
               OnClick={this._redirectCustomerView}/></View>


        _redirectCustomerView = () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('UserHome');
          };
```

// Below is home page

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { title: 'Hello!', hasFooterPermission: false };
        console.log("Valuueeeeeee");
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        const homeFooter = await hasPermission('clm.360D.fe.restrictedView.allowed');

        this.setState({
          hasFooterPermission: homeFooter
        })
      }

      onSearchClick = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SubscriberSearch');
      };
      componentWillMount(){
        console.log(" Home page dataaaa");
      }


      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <ImageBackground source={BG} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} resizeMode="cover">
              <View  style={{ paddingTop: 5 , alignContent:'space-between',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start', flex:1}}>
                  <UserAvatar navigationProps={this.props.navigation} avatarSize={40} isTouchable={true}/>
                </View>
                {/* <View style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}>
                  <Icon
                    name="bell-outline"
                    type="MaterialCommunityIcons"
                    style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}
                    onPress={() => Toastr.showToast('No new notifications!', 3000)}
                  />
                </View> */}
              </View>
```

Answer (score 18):

use push instead of navigate

```
this.props.navigation.push('UserHome');
```

Comment: This is the right answer, Thanks Shanker.

Comment: How to pass parameters to this then? push('UserHome',{paramaetes}) not working

Answer (score 0):

It is not homepage duty to know if you have to refresh the page. The suggested approach is that when the condition to reload is met (avatar update, user properties changes, etc) then the calling entity should go to the homepage and if needed ask for a reload (i.e., `window.location.reload(true)`)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a listener on the home page through the navigation prop, you can call a function when a transition to or from the home page is about to happen ('willFocus'/'willBlur') or if it has completed ('didFocus'/'didBlur').
This worked for me:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus',this.load)
}
load = () => {
  //whatever you want to do when the page loads
}
```

Documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html